# Select com 2 Inner Join não retorna resultado

Tags: sql, sql-select, inner-join

Tenho um banco de dados relacional que tem 3 tabelas: tb_funcionarios, tb_licencas e tb_tipo_licencas, cada uma com suas respectivas chaves primárias. A tabela tb_licencas, no entanto, tem as chaves das outras duas tabelas. A questão é: como fazer uma consulta na tabela tb_licencas que traga os campos desta tabela e os campos das outras duas associados cada um à sua própria chave? Tentei usar Inner Join, mas ele só funciona com duas tabelas. Quando tento acrescentar um 2 inner join a consulta simplesmente não me retorna nada. Segue a Query:

```html
SELECT tb_licencas.IdLicença, tb_licencas.IdFuncionário, tb_funcionarios.Nome, tb_funcionarios.Matrícula, tb_funcionarios.Admissão, tb_funcionarios.Regime, tb_funcionarios.Cargo, tb_tipos_licencas.IdTipo, tb_tipos_licencas.Descrição, tb_licencas.Órgão, tb_licencas.Início, tb_licencas.Duração, tb_licencas.TérminoIndeterminado, tb_licencas.Cancelado, tb_licencas.Cancelamento, tb_licencas.CancelamentoMotivo, tb_licencas.CancelamentoObservação, tb_licencas.Anotações, tb_licencas.Inativo
FROM tb_licencas 
INNER JOIN tb_funcionarios ON tb_licencas.IdFuncionário = tb_funcionarios.IdFuncionário 
INNER JOIN tb_tipos_licencas ON tb_licencas.IdTipo = tb_tipos_licencas.IdTipo
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, eu agradeço muito.

O banco de dados que tô usando é o SQL CE.

Comment: Sintaticamente está correto. O problema de não retornar nada pode ter a ver com os dados existentes nas tabelas. Se possível monte um exemplo no SQLFiddle para que possamos testar.

Comment: Verdade... Eu tinha lançado os dados manualmente nas tabelas e os dados estavam inconsistentes. O problema é só os valores de chaves primárias e estrangeiras da tabela tb_funcionarios que estavam errados. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Já agora, se há algum problema de inconsistência, convém que no desenho das tabelas, as Foreign Keys estejam lá, só mesmo para evitar que se lancem dados na tb_licencas que não estejam nas tabelas mães.